Reset Nvidia bluefield from remote
I'm trying to configure a Nvidia bluefield-2 to work in EMBEDDED_CPU mode, following this tutorial https://medium.com/codex/nvidia-mellanox-bluefield-2-smartnic-dpdk-rig-for-dive-part-ii-change-mode-of-operation-a994f0f0e543. The problem is that after I changed the mode and rebooted the host, I can't connect anymore to the smartNIC via ssh. In particular the output of mst status -v is the following:
MST modules:
------------
    MST PCI module is not loaded
    MST PCI configuration module loaded
PCI devices:
------------
DEVICE_TYPE             MST                           PCI       RDMA            NET                                     NUMA
BlueField2(rev:0)       /dev/mst/mt41686_pciconf0.1   81:00.1                                                            1

BlueField2(rev:0)       /dev/mst/mt41686_pciconf0     81:00.0                                                            1

In the NET section I don't have anything anymore. Is there a way to reset the smartNIC? I only have remote access to the host, so I can't physically act on the board.
